# Why did the author cite "Paris" in this article?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The restaurant is in Barcelona, but the author cited "Paris" and said "They must be starving in Paris".
Why?

> La Vermuteria del Tano
>
> OK, so **Paris** has its pavement bars and quaint lampposts. But we’ve got bodegas like Tano's. A door covered in stickers, marble tables, the smell of long-gone cigars still somehow lingering, and the young woman with the Sunday paper under her arm who chats away as she sips on her vermouth and snacks on anchovies, olives and cockles. They must be starving in **Paris**.

source: https://www.timeout.com/barcelona/restaurants/la-vermuteria-del-tano

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "we" (Barcelona) and "they" (Paris)?

Comment: The author mentions Paris because she wants to compare typical restaurants from Paris with the one that she is talking about. The parisiens must be starving because all the (good) food is in Barcelona, I guess. The phrase got not much sense, I agree with you.

Comment: @RubioRic This comment would make a great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author mentions Paris because she wants to compare typical restaurants from Paris with the one that she is talking about located in Barcelona.

The parisiens must be starving because all the (good) food is in Barcelona, I guess. The phrase got not much sense, I agree with you.